# Project (lat,lng) GPS point to a line segment (road segment)

Tags: coordinates

Is there a way to project a point `A` to a `B,C` line segment and find a point `D` ? The points are latitude, longitude points, so I believe we should incorporate the haversine distance formula.

Edit: I am trying to do something line this, but with GPS coordinates.

[image: 1]

Comment: Would something like ClosestPoint in SpatiaLite work for you https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html?

Comment: Could you draw a sketch about what you are planning to do? Can the projected point D be on the extension of segment B,C or must it be between vertices B and C?

Comment: Do you mean by "each edge is a list of nodes" that your edges can have more than two nodes?

Comment: I think you should include a picture and a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I edited my question. There is no ambiguity now.